# Function<? super T, ? extends Comparable> does not accept objects of super types of T?

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

I am dealing with the following puzzle.

```
class Product {}

static class Fruit extends Product implements Comparable<Fruit> {}

class Apple extends Fruit {}

Function<? super Fruit, ? extends Comparable> fx = Fruit::getCost;
Fruit fruit = new Fruit(1);
Product product = new Product();
fx.apply(product); <-- compile error?
```

What might be the reason fx not to accept Product object as argument? Product is parent of Fruit i.e. satisfies "? super Fruit" definition.

```
Function<? extends Fruit, ? extends Comparable> fx = Fruit::getCost;
Fruit fruit = new Fruit(1);
Apple apple = new Apple(2);
fx.apply(apple); <-- compile error?
```

Why apple would not be accepted as argument when its type is subtype of Fruit? Apple should satisfy "? extends Fruit".

Comment: What do your error messages say is the problem?

Comment: See [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/6395627). The `? super Fruit` means the `Function` _implementation_ is capable of handling `Fruit` **itself** or a supertype. That means only instances of `Fruit` can be consumed. Imagine if the compiler allowed you to pass a `Product` instance but the implementation expects a `Fruit`; that wouldn't work out well. As for why `? extends Fruit` doesn't work, that's because now the _implementation_ may expect any specific subtype of `Fruit`, not just any `Fruit` type.

Comment: The fact that your function is defined as `Fruit::getCost` should already hint to you that there can’t be any construct allowing to pass a `Product` to that function, regardless of how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think logically about what a `Function<? super Fruit, ? extends Comparable>` could be (for four examples):

1. It could be a function which maps `Fruit` objects to something comparable.
2. It could be a function which maps `Product` objects to something comparable.
3. It could be a function which maps `Comparable<Fruit>` to something comparable.
4. It could be a function which maps `Object` objects to something comparable.

In cases 2. and 4., a `Product` object meets the requirements to be a parameter of the function, but in cases 1. and 3. - where the function only accepts `Fruit` or `Comparable<Fruit>` - a `Product` is not a valid argument for the function. So the function might not be callable with your argument of type `Product`.

---

Let's think about what a `Function<? extends Fruit, ? extends Comparable>` could be (for four examples):

1. It could be a function which maps `Fruit` objects to something comparable.
2. It could be a function which maps `Apple` objects to something comparable.
3. It could be a function which maps `Banana` objects to something comparable.
4. It could be a function which maps some subclass of `Apple` to something comparable.

In cases 1. and 2., an `Apple` object meets the requirements to be a parameter of the function, but in cases 3. and 4. - where the function only accepts `Banana` or some subclass of `Apple` - an `Apple` is not a valid argument for the function. So the function might not be callable with your argument of type `Apple`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something and that helped me to understand the problem:

```
    Function<Fruit, ? extends Comparable> fx1 = Fruit::getCost;
    Function<? super Fruit, ? extends Comparable> fx2 = fx1;
    fx2.apply(new Product()); <-- COMPILER ERROR
```

Function fx2, which is fx1 knows/expects a Fruit. If the compiler allows Product this would be a problem.

```
    Function<Apple, ? extends Comparable> fx1 = Fruit::getCost;
    Function<? extends Fruit, ? extends Comparable> fx2 = fx1;
    fx2.apply(new Fruit(1));    <-- COMPILER ERROR
```

Function fx2, which is fx1 knows/expects a Apple. If the compiler allows Fruit this would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will clarify things:

```
Function<Fruit, Integer> costFunc = Fruit::getCost;
Function<? super Fruit, ? extends Comparable<?>> fx = costFunc;
```

Every object with a generic typing has *exact type arguments.*  While you can *refer* to a Function as `Function<? super Fruit, …>`, there is no such thing as an object of that type.  There is a Function<Fruit, …>, a Function<Product, …>, and a Function<Object, …>, but no existing object can actually be of a wildcard type (that is, a type which uses a question mark).  The `?` is only a way to tell the compiler that you *aren’t sure* what the object’s actual generic type is.

In the above code, the compiler sees that `fx` is declared as `Function<? super Fruit, ? extends Comparable<?>>`.  The compiler doesn’t know what the actual generic type of the Function’s input parameter is, because you have told it that it’s *some specific type* which might be Fruit, or any class or interface inherited by Fruit.

So the compiler doesn’t know whether it’s safe to pass a Product to the `apply` method.  What if `fx` holds a Function which requires a Fruit, not just any Product, as the first argument?  Meaning, a `Function<Fruit, …>` (which is what the example shows)?

If you want to declare a Function which accepts Fruit or any supertype of Fruit, you would write `Function<Object, …>` without using any wildcard at all.

Answer (score 1):

The type signature of `fx` is `<? super Fruit>-><? extends Comparable<?>>`. In a method call, assigning arguments to parameters is like assigning values to variables. You can only assign a value to a variable if the type of the value is the same, or a subtype of, that of the variable. Is `Product` a subtype of `<? super Fruit>`?

No.